# How to parse data from a big string using php?

Tags: php, parsing

i got a big string as shown below(number of sets of data is not known):

```
  p '5123': {
            p 'tmp': p '1', p 'name': p 'mango', p 'abc': p 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234', p 'number': p '1123', p 'itemCategory_title': p 'fruits', p 'logo': p '2123.png', p 'itemCategory_id': p '90'
        }, p '700': {
            p 'tmp': p '0', p 'name': p 'cherry', p 'abc': p 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235', p 'number': p '1124', p 'itemCategory_title': p 'fruits', p 'logo': p '2124.png', p 'itemCategory_id': p '91'
        }, p '800': {
....................
```

i want to extract the following data from it and create a hyperlink for each set of data! (extract following values: tmp,name,abc,number,itemCategory_title,logo,itemCategory_id)

could any one tell me how i can extract the following data ?Thanks in advance.

sample one set of data to extract :

```
tmp=1
 name=mango
 abc=abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234
 number=1123
 itemCategory_title=fruits
 log=2123.png
 itemCategory_id=90
```

output this html hyperlinks via php:

```
<a href="./process.php?tmp=1&name=mango&abc=abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234&number=1123&itemCategory_title=fruits&log=2123.png&itemCategory_id=90">mango </a> <br />
<a href="./process.php?tmp=1&name=cherry&abc=abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235&number=1124&itemCategory_title=fruits&log=2124.png&itemCategory_id=91">cherry </a> <br />
```

code2 holds the sample input string:

```
    $code2 = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);
$clean_str = str_replace("p '","'",$code2);

$serialized = serialize($clean_str);
$expected_array = unserialize($serialized);
print_r($expected_array);


      // iterate the new array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($expected_array); $i++){
    ?>
    <a href="./process.php?tmp=<?php  echo $expected_array['tmp'] ; ?>&name=<?php  echo $expected_array['name'] ; ?>&abc=<?php  echo $expected_array['abc'] ; ?>&itemCategory_title=<?php  echo $expected_array['itemCategory_title'] ; ?>&log=<?php  echo $expected_array['log'] ; ?>&itemCategory_id=<?php  echo $expected_array['itemCategory_id'] ; ?>"><?php  echo $expected_array['itemCategory_title'] ; ?> </a> <br />
    <?
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . i don't know how to use preg_match_all for this type of data!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick here. If you know the p is common everywhere then remove it from the string.

```
$str = "{ p '5123': {
            p 'tmp': p '1', p 'name': p 'mango', p 'abc': p 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234', p 'number': p '1123', p 'itemCategory_title': p 'fruits', p 'logo': p '2123.png', p 'itemCategory_id': p '90'
        }, p '700': {
            p 'tmp': p '0', p 'name': p 'cherry', p 'abc': p 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235', p 'number': p '1124', p 'itemCategory_title': p 'fruits', p 'logo': p '2124.png', p 'itemCategory_id': p '91'
        } }";
$clean_str = str_replace("p '","'",$str);
```

Now it seems like json string;

```
$expected_array = json_decode($clean_str);
```

Comment: Thanks pratik soni . i tried to use your method but clean_str is showing empty using this method $clean_str = preg_replace("/p\s'","'",$code2);
echo $clean_str; AND textarea is empty <textarea rows="30" cols="150"><?PHP  echo $clean_str; ?></textarea>  i want to see the clean_str data before i deal with the array

Comment: I have edited the code. Replaced preg_replace with str_replace. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks now it removed the p values. How to reference each array item so i use it inside for loop to construct the hyperlinks ?