# How to parse json string inside loop?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want to parse json string inside a loop . I tried using the following code but the parsed data never prints out inside the loop! could any one tell me what i am doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

$code2 sample data:

```
{ p '5123': {
            p 'tmp': p '1', p 'name': p 'mango', p 'abc': p 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234', p 'number': p '1123', p 'itemCategory_title': p 'fruits', p 'logo': p '2123.png', p 'itemCategory_id': p '90'
        }, p '700': {
            p 'tmp': p '0', p 'name': p 'cherry', p 'abc': p 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235', p 'number': p '1124', p 'itemCategory_title': p 'fruits', p 'logo': p '2124.png', p 'itemCategory_id': p '91'
        } }
```

$clean_str data:

```
{ '5123': {
            'tmp': '1', 'name': 'mango', 'abc': 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234', 'number': '1123', 'itemCategory_title': 'fruits', 'logo': '2123.png', 'itemCategory_id': '90'
        }, '700': {
            'tmp': '0', 'name': 'cherry', 'abc': 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235', 'number': '1124', 'itemCategory_title': 'fruits', 'logo': '2124.png', 'itemCategory_id': '91'
        } }
```

php code:

```
<?
$code2 = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);
$clean_str = str_replace("p '","'",$code2);

$data = json_decode($clean_str);

foreach( $data as $item ) {
  echo $item['tmp'];
  echo $item['name'];
  echo $item['abc'];
  echo $item['number'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_title'];
  echo $item['log'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_id'];    

?>
<a href="./process.php?tmp=<?php  echo $item['tmp'] ; ?>&name=<?php  echo $item['name']; ?>&abc=<?php  echo $item['abc'] ; ?>&itemCategory_title=<?php  echo $item['itemCategory_title'] ; ?>&log=<?php  echo $item['log'] ; ?>&itemCategory_id=<?php  echo $item['itemCategory_id'] ; ?>"><?php  echo $item['itemCategory_title'] ; ?>test </a> <br />
<?

}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse data from a big string using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802833/how-to-parse-data-from-a-big-string-using-php)

Comment: To get array with json_decode add second param  TRUE ($string, TRUE).. or you are going to catch object not array..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed it to $data = json_decode($clean_str, true); but still did not parse the json string inside loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a result as an array you should:

```
$data = json_decode($clean_str, true);
```

JSON uses double quotes " not single '

```
<?php

$code2 = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);

$clean_str = str_replace("p '","'",$code2);
$clean_str = str_replace('\'', '"', $clean_str);

$data = json_decode($clean_str, true);

foreach( $data as $item ) {
  echo $item['tmp'];
  echo $item['name'];
  echo $item['abc'];
  echo $item['number'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_title'];
  echo $item['log'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_id'];    

?>
<a href="./process.php?tmp=<?php  echo $item['tmp'] ; ?>&name=<?php  echo $item['name']; ?>&abc=<?php  echo $item['abc'] ; ?>&itemCategory_title=<?php  echo $item['itemCategory_title'] ; ?>&log=<?php  echo $item['log'] ; ?>&itemCategory_id=<?php  echo $item['itemCategory_id'] ; ?>"><?php  echo $item['itemCategory_title'] ; ?>test </a> <br />
<?

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . I tried that but still didn't parse the json string!could you tell me if the json string has the correct format ?

Comment: Json uses double quotes " not single ' :)

Comment: @faressoftThe data is from an api response so i have no control over how to construct it! So how i can change all single quotes back to double quotes?i tried this but didn't wrok!$clean_str = str_replace("'",""",$code2);

Comment: $clean_str = str_replace('\'', '"', $clean_str);

Comment: thanks your solution worked and also this one fixed the problem: $clean_str = str_replace("'","\"",$code2);
$clean_str = str_replace("p ","",$clean_str);